# Split Front/Rear/Aux on Mic/Input ports on one sound card to different capture sources (Pulseaudio/ALSA)

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I have an Asus Xonar DG installed in my Pop OS (Ubuntu 19.04 flavor) machine.

I was wondering if I am able to separate the different capture sources into discrete inputs for use in Jack and streaming stuff from my Aux/Front Mic to, say, Audacity while keeping my microphone working in Discord.

[image: Photo of different port options]

Here is the photo of the different port options I can choose from..

And they do all show up in Alsamixer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple capture sources at the same time is possible only if there are multiple capture devices (in the output of `arecord -l`), or if it is possible to route these sources to different channels of the same capture device.

The CS4245 chip used on the Xonar DG has a single (stereo) ADC, so this is not possible.

Comment: Well what if instead of the Xonar DG, we assume I'm using the motherboard's built-in Realtek Audio Chipset, which I have used successfully in the example configuration (even going so far as to use the program Virtual Audio Cable to mix the two "mics" into one virtual microphone to use in VOIP programs).

Comment: I don't know the specific chipset model, but the motherboard is a GA-Z97X-Gaming from Gigabyte.